# Unsure how to use these dry wall anchors?

Tags: drywall, anchor, drywall-anchor

I am trying to install a floating shelf unit and the included wall anchors are these.

[image]

I've tried following the guide [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4x-32b0KSv4) but it seems that mine have two tabs sticking out that stops them from folding "up" (towards the screw hole like in the video), however they do fold "down" (towards the vertex of the "V" shape) and was wondering if that was indeed the intended way instead, and would still work?

Comment: What kind of walls do you have?

Comment: I believe it is dry wall with wooden supports/studs.

Answer (score 5):

Throw them away.  These are terrible anchors.  There are better ones for every type of wall.  I never use the hardware that comes with anything to attach to walls.  Learn how the walls of your home are built and find great anchors and screws that you learn to use well and can rely on.

For drywall with wood studs (per your comment) and for light to medium loads without a lot of pullout (no TVs!) these IMO are the best.  Easiest to use, most consistent, most versatile, least prone to failure.   If you have a stud finder use it, otherwise drill a tiny pilot hole before using these plugs.  If you hit a stud don't use the plug, just use a long wood screw by itself and ALSO not the one that came with your shelf ... buy good wood screws.

[image]

Comment: I've had mediocre luck with these -- they tend to snap before I get them all the way into the sheetrock.

Comment: Are you sure it's sheetrock and sure there is nothing else backing it?

Comment: Thanks for the input!  Do you have a preferred brand for these as it seems Home Depot/Lowe's has a decent selection?

Comment: These are the best. Really important to use the proper diameter screw though.

Comment: I don't have a preferred brand.  Don't buy no-name crap from a big online retailer where you get 500 pieces for $1.50.  Buy a good brand name from a store you trust, one that seems to be selling well.  If it works for you, you will learn its ins and outs, you will learn how to avoid breaking it or breaking your wall (it will happen) and you will get good at it.  If the one you choose has a consistent flaw,  try another one.

Answer (score 2):

The ones you have do fold though they don't seem to want to. The center of the lower pieces are pushed upward while pushing the upper pieces down to form a slimmer post to insert in the gypsum board and the accompanying screw twists into the lower piece's hole tightly while moving the four pieces back to against the inside of the wall board.

But, I agree with jay613, in that the wall anchor he posted is better. It also is easier to remove and leaves a cleaner hole to repair when and if you do remove it. Don't over tighten it to the point of breaking the wall board or stripping the hole. A slight indentation in the wall board is what you should expect. I've used the metal and plastic (shown by jay613) for many years and some come in weight grades as to how much weight they should hold.

Good luck!